# vb.net passing variable from .aspx.vb to .aspx javascript variable

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net

How do I pass a variable defined in .aspx.vb to .aspx.

I've tried this in the .aspx.vb:

```
Partial Class show_zoos
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
'database logic

Dim postcode As String = an.Postcode
 End Sub
End class
```

And this for priting it out in the .aspx:

```
var postcode = '<%=postcode%>'
```

I got the following error:

'postcode' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

postcode needs to be min visibility Protected.

```
Public postcode As String
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        postcode = "ABCD"
    End Sub
```

Comment: Just to be a little more clear, variables need to be declared at the class level, not the method level.

Comment: Thanks Chris Haas. I did mean that.

Also the minimum visibility of the variables should be protected level too. Should not be private.